# Ошибка импорта Mapping from collections

Tags: python, python-3.x

при попытке запустить скрипт на питоне, постоянно выскакивает это:

```
PS C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\AutoShop> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\AutoShop\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import telebot, sqlite3, time, datetime, requests, configparser, random
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from telebot import apihelper, util, types
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 10, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .wait import wait_for_read
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: У вас ошибка на второй строчке

Comment: а что непонятного из текста ошибки (в самом низу). Вы имgортируете Mapping из collections, а его там нет.

Answer (score 4):

Для новых версий Python (начиная с 3.8) нужно импортировать `Mapping` из нового модуля `abc` внутри `collections`.
Если вам нужен код, совместимый со всеми версиями, можно сделать так:

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from collections import Mapping
```

Если достаточно работоспособности только на свежих версиях, то достаточно строчки:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать что мне сделать с этим? Я новичок)

Comment: Я же в тексте ответа всё написал. Если вам не нужно, чтобы код корректно работал на версиях Python ниже 3.8, просто импортируете из модуля abc, как описано в последней строчке. Если нужно, то используете конструкцию try-except, описанную выше.